# How to use the @natlibfi/marc-record package to generate a Marc 21 file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a question about how to generate a Marc 21 file using the @natlibfi/marc-record package. I created a class that contains the methods to define the value of each field in the file. And at the end of the class I have a method called build that calls the "toString" method, but the code generated is not the one expected to write to the file but an object as shown below. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

```
{
  "record": {
    "_validationOptions": {
       "fields": false
    },
    "leader": "00000cam a2200000 a 4500",
    "fields": [
        {
          "tag": "245",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "code": "a",
              "value": "Jesus para estressados"
            }
              ],
              "ind1": " ",
              "ind2": " "
            }
    ]
   }
}
```

I was expecting the @natlibfi/marc-record package to generate the content that should be inserted into a ".mrc" file.